Hide contour lines (edges) for specific object within the same model Forge Viewer
Is there a way to hide contour lines for a specific object within the same model (and keep contour lines for the rest of the model)
I know, how to hide contour lines for the whole model, if you pass this parameter createWireframe: false when calling a loadModel() function, all contour lines will be hidden.
But is it possible to hide contour lines for just a few objects withing one model, targeting them by dbId or using fragments somehow?
I've tried applying a custom material with shader, but it didn't work out, when I applied that material, I got WebGl errors.
I've tried to apply material for each fragment of an object separately or hide them, but it didn't affect the contour lines at all. I've checked the source code and looks like that parameter which controls contour lines is just passed to an api and I didn't find a part where those lines would be created as part of geometry.

I'm afraid this is not something that would be easily doable, i.e., not without drilling into the internals of the APS Viewer rendering pipeline. What exactly is the use case for this kind of customization?
